# Unable to write exact sql query to get result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have below type of data set:

```
Base    Col1    Col2    Col3
1000    0        10     1100
1100    0        10     1210
1210    0        10     1331
```

For deriving col3, I will use formula like

```
col3 = (base - col1) * (1 + col2 / 100)
```

If you observe above data set 1st row of col3 value is the second row base column value. And Col2 value is same for all records.

So now my problem is at later point of time my col1 (Col1 column is a part of formula) row values will update based on this i need to recalculate col3 values by using mentioned formula.

See below data set for example, if col1 value has updates then we need to recalculate col3 values like below by using formula (Col3=(base-col1)*(1+col2/100))

```
Base    Col1    Col2    Col3
 1000    10      10     1089
 1089    20      10     1175.9
 1175.9  30      10     1293.4
```

For getting above data set, I have tried like below.

```
SELECT 
    col1, col2, 
    col3 - SUM(col1 * (Power((1 + COL2 / 100.00), RNO))) 
              OVER(ORDER BY RNO ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM
    (SELECT 
         row_number() OVER(ORDER BY col1) rno,
         *
     FROM   
         #TABLE1) A
```

But I am not getting the correct results.

Please use below script to create table and for populating data.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
  (
     [col1] INT,
     [col2] INT,
     [col3] INT
  );

INSERT INTO #Table1
            ([col1],
             [col2],
             [col3])
VALUES      (10,10, 1100),
            (20,10,1210),
            (30,10,1331);
```

Note:- In my example always base value will dependent on previous row col3 value.

Please help me.

Comment: If the value in col3 is calculated actually and should change together with the values in col1 and col2 why don't you use a [computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx)?

Comment: @Shnugo I think computed column will not work because my base column value will always change. It depends on previous row col3.

Comment: Ah, I see, you are re-inventing Excel :-) Joke aside: Thorsten Kettner's first sentence is really true: *You should not store calculation results in your table* (only exception: real performance issues).

Comment: have you solved? have you found any answer useful?

Answer (score 2):

You should not store calculation results in your table. This is redundant and can lead to wrong data, as you notice. Your table also lacks an order. So first thing: Give the records a timestamp or a number. Then remove Col3 and Base. (Well, you must have the initial base value of course, so either keep the base column and make all values null except for the first one or store the value somewhere else or use a fix value in your query.)

```
Rno   Col1   Col2
1     0      10 
2     0      10 
3     0      10
```

To get the results you need a recursive query. Below query considers RNOs as adjacent (with a non-adjacent number or dates, you'd have to use row_number to number your rows first). Here I just use 1000 as the base. If this is variable, store it somewhere and take it from there.

```
with cte(rno, base, col1, col2, col3) as
(
  select rno, 1000 as base, col1, col2, (1000 - col1) * (1 + col2/100) as col3
  from mytable
  where rno = 1
  union all
  select m.rno, cte.col3 as base, m.col1, m.col2, (cte.col3 - m.col1) * (1 + m.col2/100)
  from mytable m
  join cte on m.rno = cte.rno + 1
)
select * from cte
order by rno;
```

You can create a view for this of course.

Answer (score 0):

When `col1` changes you need to update `col3` of same row,
When `col3` changes you need to update `Base` of next row,
When `Base` changes you need to update `col3` of same row..
and so on..

At every update of `Base`, `col1`, or `col3` run this loop:

```
declare @i int = 1

while @i<>0 begin

    update t set Col3 = newCol3 
    from (
        select top 1 base, col1, col2, col3, (base - col1) * (1 + col2 / 100.0) newCol3
        from @t
        where col3 <> (base - col1) * (1 + col2 / 100.0) 
        order by base
    ) t

    update t set base = newbase
    from (
        select top 1 base, col1, col2, col3, newbase
        from (
            select base, col1, col2, col3, LAG(col3,1,null) over (order by base) newbase
            from @t 
        ) t
        where base <> newbase
        order by base
    ) t


    if @@ROWCOUNT=0 set @i=0
end
```

output

```
base    col1    col2    col3
1000    10      10      1089
1089    20      10      1175,9
1175,9  30      10      1260,49 -- I think you have an error in your example
```